# Guardar y obtener datos del local storage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

quisiera saber cómo hago para guardar los datos de un formulario en el local storage y luego para imprimir esos datos en la tabla

Esta es mi data

```
export class Data {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public nombres: string,
    public apellidoPaterno: string,
    public apellidoMaterno: string,
    public dni: number,
    public celular: number,
  ){ }
}
```

Estuve intentando hacer, es del archivo TS

```
loadList(){
    console.log('load');
    this.data = JSON.parse(this.userService.getStudents() || '{}');
    if (this.data !== null) {
      this.showStudents == true;
    }
    else {
      this.showStudents == false;
    }
  }
```

Y esto mi servicio

```
getStudents(){
  return localStorage.getItem('getStudents');
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes al guardarlos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Utilizando local storage, la información queda almacenada en el
> navegador del usuario. persiste incluso cuando el navegador se cierre
> y se reabra. Por eso hay que controlar su almacenamiento.
>
> la interfaz Storage de la API de almacenamiento nos da acceso al
> almacenamiento local o de sesión Mediante la propiedad localStorage
> podemos acceder al objeto Storage
>
> Para conocer el estado del almacenamiento local debemos llamar a
> localstorage.length desde nuestro codigo  La propiedad de sólo lectura
> length de la interfaz Storage devuelve  un entero que indica el numero
> de elementos guardados en el objeto Storage.

Tambien en tu codigo **estas comparado** no asignado con  **this.showStudents == true**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('local storage',localStorage);
 // por defecto Storage {leng:0}
    localStorage!==undefined ?console.log('not undefined'):console.log('undefined');
    // por defecto muestra not undefined
    localStorage!==null ?console.log('not null'):console.log('null');
    // por defecto muestra not null
    localStorage.length !=0 ?console.log('hay elementos guardados'):console.log('no hay elementos guardados');
    // por defecto no hay elementos guardados usar esta
    condicion()
 }
    
    
condicion(){
    console.log('condicion');
  if (localStorage.length!= 0) {
      this.condicion = true;
    }
    else {
      this.condicion = false;
    }
    
  }
```

Lo mejor es  comparar con la propiedad length del Objeto Storage

Para no implementar una API completo un formulario guardo los datos en local storage y los represento en una tabla se puede reducir aun mas la lógica pero no lo hago para hacer mas claro el codigo y

> dejo al final los métodos a agregar a este código para vaciar el local
> storage y actualizar la condicion

```
class Data {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public nombres: string,
    
  ){ }
}
 estudiantes:Array<Data>=new Array();
 condicion=false;
public miFormulario:FormGroup;
  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ,private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.miFormulario = this.fb.group({
      id:[null,Validators.required],
      nombres:['',Validators.required]
    });
    SubmitLocal(form:FormGroup){
    localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(form.value));
  }
    
  resetForm(){
    this.miFormulario.reset();
  }
  VerLocal(){
    this.condicion=true;
    let formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data')!);
    this.estudiantes=[...this.estudiantes,formValue];
    console.log('formValue:',formValue);
    this.resetForm()
  } 
   // html
<form [formGroup]="miFormulario" >
  id:
      <input type="text" formControlName="id"><br>
      <hr>
nombres:
      <input type="text" formControlName="nombres"><br>
      <hr>
      <button type="submit" (click)="SubmitLocal(miFormulario)">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<button (click)="VerLocal()">VerLocal</button>
<br>

<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col" *ngFor="let titulo of titulos">
              {{titulo}}
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let estudiante of estudiantes">
      <td> {{estudiante.id}}</td>
      <td> {{estudiante.nombres}}</td>
       
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="condicion; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>{{ estudiantes| json }}</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>No hay Datos en local storage.</ng-template>
```

> Para quitar los datos del local storage usar

**localStorage.clear();**
Podemos hacerlo implementando el siguiente método **dentro del codigo anterior**

```
condicion(){
    console.log('condicion');
  if (localStorage.length!= 0) {
      this.condicion = true;
    }
    else {
      this.condicion = false;
    }

  }
limpiarLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.clear();
    this.condicion()
}
```

> Así la condición implementada en la vista responderá siempre
> adecuadamente a nuestro requerimiento
> Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de
> utilidad?